# Heroku displaying pagination different from locally

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, pagination

I am following an online tutorial for Ruby on Rails.

Everything seems to be working but the Heroku deployment shows different page for the Pagination.

Follow the images.
HEROKU:
[image: Heroku]

Locally:
[image: Locally]
& Codes:

app/views/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

app/views/users/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>

</li>
```

custom.scss

```
...   
 /* Users index */

    .users {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      li {
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
      }
    }
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab on Developer Tools? Perhaps a resource is not being properly loaded.

Comment: Is your concern that the users aren't lining up nicely in Heroku or that different users (or different order of users) are being shown in the first page? 

The former is likely not about pagination, the latter might be.

Comment: @cjungel I am not sure what I am supposed to look there. But I found there: "https://rocky-cove-64476.herokuapp.com/assets/application-defdb8e589d7a202635a006159aa604d2b91dcacb76223c1991f2a52f743886d.css" I think you are right!! How can I make this resource load?

Comment: @CaptainChaos my concern is that users aren't lining up nicely! ;)

Comment: @FelipeMaion what is the error? Is it a not found, is the resource being served on the same protocol as the rest of the site, have you checked for typos in the code that makes a reference to the resource?

Comment: @cjungel I was not able to spot any error msg... (never used this tool)

Comment: @cjungel but, I was able to fix the problem with precompile assets. Thank you!! Your hint was the key to the solution!

Comment: @FelipeMaion great!

Answer (score 1):

With the hint from @cjungel I was able to figure out the solution:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add -A
git commit -m "Precompile assets"
git push
git push heroku
```

Now it is working!